# Parametrized Test method in Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, nunit, cppunit, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I'm writing some test cases for my C++ project using **Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework**. Here I have a case where I have to run a same test case with different parameters.

In Nunit Framework for CPP, I can achieve this by the following code.

```
[Test, SequentialAttribute]
void MyTest([Values("A", "B")] std::string s)
{

}
```

By passing these parameters, this test will run 2 times.

```
MyTest("A")
MyTest("B")
```

Is there a similar way to achieve this in **Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework** unit test.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The CppUnitTestFramework doesn't provide for parameterized tests, but there's nothing to prevent you from simply writing a parameterized function and calling it from your tests.

```
void MyTest(char *param)
{
    // Actual test code here    
}

TEST_METHOD(MyTest_ParamA)
{
    MyTest("A");
}

TEST_METHOD(MyTest_ParamB)
{
    MyTest("B");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I have an interface and several implementations of it. Of course I do only want to write tests against the interface. Also, I do not want to copy my tests for each implementation. Therefore, I searched for a way to pass parameters to my test. Well, my solution is not very pretty but it is straightforward and the only one I came up with until now.

Here is my solution for my problem (in your case CLASS_UNDER_TEST would be the parameter you want to pass into the test):

**setup.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class VehicleInterface
{
public:
    VehicleInterface();
    virtual ~VehicleInterface();
    virtual bool SetSpeed(int x) = 0;
};

class Car : public VehicleInterface {
public:
    virtual bool SetSpeed(int x) {
        return(true);
    }
};

class Bike : public VehicleInterface {
public:
    virtual bool SetSpeed(int x) {
        return(true);
    }
};


#define CLASS_UNDER_TEST Car
#include "unittest.cpp"
#undef CLASS_UNDER_TEST


#define CLASS_UNDER_TEST Bike
#include "unittest.cpp"
#undef CLASS_UNDER_TEST
```

**unittest.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#define CONCAT2(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT2(a, b)

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;


TEST_CLASS(CONCAT(CLASS_UNDER_TEST, Test))
{
public:
    CLASS_UNDER_TEST vehicle;
    TEST_METHOD(CONCAT(CLASS_UNDER_TEST, _SpeedTest))
    {
        Assert::IsTrue(vehicle.SetSpeed(42));
    }
};
```

You will need to exclude „unittest.cpp“ from build.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple solution:

Create a vector with your test cases in TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE, then iterate over the vector in each test case.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace SomeTests
{
    TEST_CLASS(Some_Tests)
    {
    public:
        std::vector<int> myTestCases;

        TEST_METHOD_INITIALIZE(Initialize_Test_Cases)
        {
            myTestCases.push_back(1);
            myTestCases.push_back(2);
            myTestCases.push_back(3);
        }

        TEST_METHOD(Test_GreaterThanZero)
        {
            for (auto const& testCase : myTestCases)
            {
                Assert::IsTrue(testCase > 0);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is OK - but how do I know which test failed? If my test were instead `Assert::IsTrue(testCase % 2 == 1)` then I'd fail the 2 case, but all the information I'd get is that "Test_IsOdd" (renaming from GreaterThanZero) failed, not which "case" - right?